# How to show the d3 chart inside the div

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using d3 to make a chart. I am not using using any div tag. The chart is showing inside the body tag.

How can I show the d3 chart inside a div tag?

The code is below:

[click here to see the d3 chart example](http://bl.ocks.org/juan-cb/ac731adaeadd3e855d26)

Comment: Change this line: `var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")` to use the div you want. You can do `var svg = d3.select("div").append("svg")`, but this will append the SVG in the **first** div. You can select the div by class or ID, though. For instance, if the div has an ID of `someDiv`, do this: `var svg = d3.select("#someDiv").append("svg")`.

Comment: Thank you Gerardo Furtado. This is working good. leave your comment as answer, i will mark your comment as answer.

Comment: Thanks, Vinoth, but this is quite basic and, to be fair, most probably a duplicate. However, **you** can write an answer and you can even accept your own answer (in a couple of days). Write an answer explaining how to select by class, by ID or even by nth child. It will be a good exercise for you.

Comment: Grammar, punctuation changes to help the flow of the question. Removed "thanks" phrases.

Comment: :@  Gerardo Furtado, @cmonkey:Hi, Can you answer this question . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42952867/d3-dashboard-chart-data-bind-from-json-or-csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace body with div is working

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg") 
var svg = d3.select("div").append("svg"),
```